# Integrating google's refresh access token (offline) with credentials in one function

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to access user's *new* access token via a POST call from chrome extension to my website that the user gave permission to. Thus, all of google doc that's dependant on redirects & user being on the session wouldn't work for me.

I can't seem to figure out how to integrate google's [refresh access token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#offline) with User's credentials (client_id, client_secret, refresh_token, grant_type) stored in db.

```
@blueprint.route("Calendar", methods=['POST'])
def Calendar():

    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.Flow.from_client_secrets_file(
      CLIENT_SECRETS_FILE, scopes=SCOPES) #believe should be added or else flow would be undefined (even though not present in the code snippet)

    authorization_url, state = flow.authorization_url(
      # Enable offline access so that you can refresh an access token without
      # re-prompting the user for permission. Recommended for web server apps.
      access_type='offline',
      # Enable incremental authorization. Recommended as a best practice.
      include_granted_scopes='true')
```

I tried adding:

```
# Use the authorization server's response to fetch the OAuth 2.0 tokens.
authorization_response = flask.request.url
flow.fetch_token(authorization_response=authorization_response)
credentials = flow.credentials
flask.session['credentials'] = credentials

user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()  
with open('client_secret.json') as d:
    d = json.load(d)
service = build('calendar', 'v3', credentials=credentials)
```

& got:

```
oauthlib.oauth2.rfc6749.errors.MismatchingStateError: (mismatching_state) CSRF Warning! State not equal in request and response.
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not all Google samples are created alike and the Google calendar sample is lacking in an example of what you are trying to do.

Try checking the [Google Analytics quick start Python](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/installed-py) this sample has a very nice example of how to set up storage of the refresh token and how to use it when needed.

```
 # Prepare credentials, and authorize HTTP object with them.
  # If the credentials don't exist or are invalid run through the native client
  # flow. The Storage object will ensure that if successful the good
  # credentials will get written back to a file.
  storage = file.Storage('calendar.dat')
  credentials = storage.get()
  if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = tools.run_flow(flow, storage, flags)
  http = credentials.authorize(http=httplib2.Http())
```

The sample for [Google drive sample](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) also has something like it.

```
# The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
```

I am not telling you to switch APIs here i am simply suggesting that you check how the authorization code works in the other two tutorials.  You will need to pass your existing scopes for calendar and NOT the scopes for drive or analytics.  The methods you are using to access your events will not change you are only changing how the authorization functions.

I am not a python dev so cant really help you alter it more then that.

Comment: Thanks for getting back! I'm sorry if my post wasn't detailed enough. I am basically trying to make a POST call to a website that user authenticated, to retrieve the user's google calendar data. Thus, the only way to achieve that is to refresh the access token after getting refresh token all offline as I linked in the post. As mentioned, in the post my problem is with the sample offline code not working as it looks to be my only remedy. I believe in your latter example is dedicated to CLI not web application or server as similar code in (https://developers.google.com/people/quickstart/python)

Comment: I believe the former example requires `VIEW_ID` as it's related to analytics when I don't have nor would I want to confuse the user to give a permission that I won't use. Thus, as mentioned, in my post, the google folks recommended me the offline approach(https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#offline). However, I get error for both HTTP & python that I'm not sure how to go about.

Comment: Note: Im not tell you to switch to Google Analaytics or drive. I am simply telling you to follow the tutorial set out and change the scope to calendar.  They are designed using the same library there for the authorization code is exactly the same just change the scope and use the same method you are normally.   These examples will show you how to request a refresh token store it for later use and then use it when needed.  I am not a python dev so cant help you alter the code only point you at the code you can use to make it work.

Comment: I completely understand your point. I actually tried per your description & got a URL to click on from CLI with failing to start local port error. Thus, I believe both of them are CLI authentication. If I couldn't find anyway to make the HTTP work, I'll spend more time on playing around with the code you posted.

Comment: InstalledAppFlow <-- is for installed applications it will only work on the machine that the code is running on its not designed for being hosted web.   try reading though this it might help https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/25fba648ea647b62f2a6edc54ae927c1ed381b45/docs/oauth.md   Im really sorry i cant help more all i can do is point you at things really.

Comment: No worries. You've already helped a lot. Thanks for sharing the resource! I ended up making it work by doing the HTTP request.